# What language codes does the Panoramio JavaScript API support?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, localization, panoramio

What languages does the Panoramio JavaScript API support?

At http://www.panoramio.com/api/widget/api.html it's explained in the "JavaScript API" section that one may specify a language parameter. In the below example, English, or en is specified:

src="http://www.panoramio.com/wapi/wapi.js?v=1&hl=en"

In the above URL, an example specifying French, or fr, is given.

I guess you always specify a 2-letter code for the language, or, as I think it's called, a ISO 639-1 code.

So what is the list of supported languages?

Also, if one were to specify a language that is not supported, would it default to English?

Comment: https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=p9pdwsai2hDMsLkXsoM05KQ&gid=1

Comment: Thanks for that, MrUpsidown.